# Gridster widget html isn't responsive after manual resize

Tags: ember.js, gridster

I am creating a dashboard in ember and using gridster in combination of C3 charts and a bootstrap markup.

At the point I do a manual resize of a gridster widget the html isn't responsive and keeps the same/size position.

I hope someone could help me to make the C3 chart responsive. (fill up the size of the manual resized gridster widget)

A overview of my code:

```
 import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagname: "",

  didInsertElement: function(){
    Ember.$(".gridster ul").gridster({
      widget_base_dimensions: [359, 200],
      widget_margins: [5, 5],
      helper: 'clone',
      resize: {
        enabled: true,
        max_size: [3, 3],
        min_size: [1, 1]
      },
      serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
          return {
            col: wgd.col,
            row: wgd.row,
            size_x: wgd.size_x,
            size_y: wgd.size_y
          };},
    }).data('gridster');
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
        <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="2">
              {{c3-chart data=model.c3data4 color=model.color}}
    </li>
```

Comment: can u throw this into jsbin?

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vejetibisi/1/edit Is there a method like Zoom, resize or Load?